# Check manual page of check_sql always giving a warning status

Tags: mysql, performance, nagios, check-mk

I've installed OMD and activated the Check_mk interface and Nagios engine. It works like a charm except for one thing. I can't properly check my SQL. Here is what I've done so far:

Created a new database with an owner.

- DB: omd
- User: omdadmin
- Table: omdtable
- 1st column: id (int) with value 1
- 2nd column:
  name (varchar) with value "working"
- 3rd column: status (varchar) with
  value "PING ok - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.80 ms"

On the WebGUI of Check_MK I've activated `Host & Service Parameters` -> `Active Checks` -> `Check SQL Database`. For it I've set up everything and it connects just fine. I've made a `select * from omdtable`. However I receive a WARN status constantly and I've got an error message saying: `Failed to parse performance data string: performance_data=PING ok - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.80 ms` I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Can you guys give me a hint?

What did I do wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally I found what was wrong. According to documentation: https://mathias-kettner.de/cms_check_check_sql.html the result from first column is parsed and final status depends on what script finds in that first column. 
In other words, you have always WARNING status, because you INSERTED '1' instead of '0' in first column. Try to do the fallowing things:

1. Remove all data from table omdtable: DELETE FROM omdtable;
2. Add new data: INSERT INTO omdtable VALUES(0,'test);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know check_mk but i'm surprising about the status of the result of your command.
To have performance datas you should have a pipe which separate the status from the performances datas like that :

```
PING ok | Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.80 ms
```

`PING` ok is the status and `Packet loss=etc...` is the performances datas. Maybe you have a problem in the result of your command, it should return :

```
PING ok | Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.80 ms
```

and not :

```
PING ok - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.80 ms
```

to have your perf datas and nagios be able to parse yours results.

Comment: I've tested the connection via telnet and the command `telnet CLIENT-IP 6556` and I've received all the data, but there is no such word `PING` in it. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Might be a lame question, sorry if it is: How do I retrieve performance data? I believe that is what Check_mk is expecting to be in my 3rd column.

Comment: If you can, you should change the 3rd column and replace the - by a pipe |.

Comment: Is comes back with the same error :(

Comment: sorry replace the comma by ; and delete in right side on of the equal caracter : |Packet_loss=0%; RTA=0.80 ms

Comment: Nope. :( A Check_MK expert would be nice to have now...